# How to improve RealityKit physics simulation accuracy?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, physics-engine

I've been trying to build a Billiard game based on RealityKit, but the physics simulation is not accurate enough. Seems like RealityKit produces rough calculations when parameters are too small.

The following code presents what I've done so far. Is there a way to config RealityKit and improve physics accuracy?

```
import RealityKit
import ARKit

let ballMaterial = PhysicsMaterialResource.generate(friction: 0.055, restitution: 0.95)

game.allBalls.forEach { entity in
    guard let physicsEntity = entity as? HasPhysics else { return }
    
    physicsEntity.physicsBody?.massProperties.mass = 0.17
    physicsEntity.physicsBody?.material = ballMaterial
}

let wallMaterial = PhysicsMaterialResource.generate(friction: 0.005, restitution: 0.5)

game.wallEntities.forEach { entity in
    guard let physicsEntity = entity as? HasPhysics else { return }
    
    physicsEntity.physicsBody?.material = wallMaterial
}

let tableSurfaceMatrial = PhysicsMaterialResource.generate(staticFriction: 0.001, dynamicFriction: 0.2, restitution: 0.25)

game.tableSurfaceEntities.forEach { entity in
    guard let physicsEntity = entity as? HasPhysics else { return }
    
    physicsEntity.physicsBody?.material = tableSurfaceMatrial
}
```

Add a force to move white ball:

```
// ballWhite as? Entity & HasPhysics
game.ballWhite.physicsBody?.mode = .dynamic
game.ballWhite.addForce(rayForce, relativeTo: nil)
```

[ModelEntity: render physics entity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/modelentity/)

[HasPhysics: physics protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/hasphysics)

[Falling ball](https://youtu.be/EyV_BDH8yX4)

Answer (score 1):

If you set `restitution` parameter to a value that is greater than `1`, RealityKit physics engine starts producing more realistic bouncing simulation, but still not realistic enough when the dynamic effect decays – Apple engineers must work harder to implement robust physics simulation in RealityKit 3.0.

I used a simple Reality Composer scene containing a ball with a radius of 0.1 m.

```
import AppKit
import RealityKit

class GameViewController: NSViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {

        arView.environment.background = .color(.black)
        
        let ballScene = try! Experience.loadBall()

        let ball = ballScene.sphere!.children[0] as! ModelEntity
        
        ball.components[CollisionComponent.self] = 
                        CollisionComponent(shapes: [.generateSphere(radius: 0.1)], 
                                             mode: .default, 
                                           filter: .sensor)

        ball.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self] = 
                        PhysicsBodyComponent(shapes: [.generateSphere(radius: 0.1)], 
                                               mass: 0.05, 
                                           material: .generate(friction: 0.9, 
                                                            restitution: 1.35))
        
        arView.scene.anchors.append(ballScene)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I see you set restitution to 1.35, more than 1.Do you mean get more speed after collision?Official documentation says restitution between [0, 1].

Official link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/physicsmaterialresource/3244780-generate

Comment: Apple documentation is great, but sometimes it also gives you some "space" for experimentation...

Comment: Simulate a falling ball is one thing, maybe we can set up special parameter only for ball.But in this way, I think simulate whole billiard game is too difficult.Is there third-party physics-engine we can work with ARKit.

Comment: I like `Newton Game Dynamics` third-party engine. It's written in C++ and it supports iOS. You can see how it works in `10 Pin Shuffle Bowling` – https://apps.apple.com/app/10-pin-shuffle-bowling/id341894188. This engine has awesome simulation accuracy.

Comment: You should also look at my favorite iOS `3D-Pool-Game` – https://apps.apple.com/app/3d-pool-game/id1175740795.  Physics engine is precise here. Probably, it's based on Unity engine...

Comment: I found https://github.com/AdamEisfeld/PhyKit, maybe it's good and easy enough for me